# mysql how to store and search urls

Tags: mysql, url, search, store

I am developing a custom CMS as part of a bigger app. The idea is that each article/post should be searchable given its unique url (slug) . Having in mind that the blog will have big and only increasing amount of posts and come under heavy load with many searches each time a user request given url, I had to figure out the most optimal way for the articles' urls should be stored and consequently searched up on. After fair amount of reading up on the net I decided to make a copy of each url and save as hashed BINARY(16) (using UNHEX MD5) and give it unique index.

But I'm wondering if this solution is indeed the correct path to follow. What do you think about it, is it the way to go or should I reconsider and take completely different approach. Is there perhaps any other, generally known paradigm to go by when designing similar functionality (a cms) where posts need to be searched efficiently and quickly by their urls/strings under considerable load, perhaps something used in other cmss like Wordpress etc.

Comment: IMHO:  If you are going to reinvent the wheel, then you need to understand why you are reinventing it and how your solution will be better.  There are so many open source CMS out there (Drupal, Wordpress, eZ publish are three PHP CMS I can quickly think of)  Do yourself a favor, read how they are doing it.  Its not like those solutions are hiding their techniques.  Frankly, it appears as though you are asking for opinions without doing any preliminary research.

Comment: @AgRizzo Far from reinventing any wheels. The custom 'cms' is merely a result and part of a bigger picture of requirements, hence its existence in the first place. Did research, came up with my solution which I presented here. The question asks very specifically: is the solution I've chosen sound in this context (storing/searching urls/strings) , if not what would be better one and if it correlates to any known approaches that may be generally preferred (wordpress given just as reference/example). Note the question title: **how to store/search urls** not **how CMSs work in general**

Comment: Edited the question accordingly

Comment: If your index is based on a hash, doesn't that mean the only way to search is with an exact match? For instance, if the slug is 'howto_search_with_MySQL;, isn't the only way to leverage the index is if someone types in that exact value (case sensitive)?  And if someone used the terms 'search by mysql', you would not be able to find this article?